# IDEFoundation.IDETemplateParseError error 1

Tags: ios, xcode, ide, xcode9.2

The error is: `The operation couldn't be completed`
(IDEFoundation.IDETemplateParseError error 1.)
(I can't upload image.. it's a error window)

I have update the xcode to the version Version 9.2 (9C40b), when I try to create a new file, this error is appear. And after I create a new project I also can't create new file. I don't know why?  I have try to `reDownload` the `xcode` and update the `xcode`, but it no use. How should I do?

Answer (score 2):

When I tried to use the Coredata and compile the .xcdatamodeld file, it showed the same problem like you.

SOLUTIONS:

1. If you don't want to use the Coredata, just delete the .xcdatamodeld file in the Build Phases-Compile Sources.
2. If you want to use the Coredata, just delete the old .xcdatamodeld file and create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you may have your organization named in a way that conflicts with the document template creation process. Check the "Organization" field for your Project, and make sure it does not have characters like underscore. For example, suppose your organization is Apple. I can reproduce your problem by replacing it with __Apple__ , and then trying to add a new file to the project. XCode 9.2 under High Sierra gives me the exact same problem. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your data model does not contain special characters in the filename. Underscores caused this error for me. ThisIsAValidName.xcdatamodeld but This_Is_Not_Valid.xcdatamodeld

Comment: This solved my problem. Interestingly xcode had generated the model file with underscores in its name. Dont forget to change         let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "NewNameOfTheModel") in AppDelegate

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my Core Data file and created a new core data file by clicking new file. I also added Entity. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

This comment helped me: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/693840?answerId=695153022#695153022

---

You have new agreement to sign. Link to appstore connect agreements: https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/agreements/#/

**Agreements** -> **View Terms**

Here is the screenshot: [image]